# bash if statement binary operator

Tags: bash, macos

Please tell me why I am an idiot and what I did wrong, because I am an idiot.
I want to have the script know if Homebrew is installed or not, so why does this return

```
test.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
```

Line 3 is as follows:

```
if [["$(brew -v)" ?? git ]]; then
```

Comment: `??` is not a bash operator

Comment: How does that tell you if Homebrew is installed?

Comment: `[["...` is not a bash operator, but `[[ "...` with a **space** is.

Comment: @SiKing : What would `??` do? Is this a new feature in bash 5? In my bash man  page, this operator is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a command exist `brew` here, use `command -v brew`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if command -v brew >/dev/null
then
  printf 'Brew is installed\n'
else
  printf 'Brew is not installed\n' >&2
fi
```